# Snap Geometries to Layer_Behavior Inquiry

Tags: qgis, transportation

When I used "snap geometries to layer" to snap a point layer to the nearest road network, I used the snap behavior "Prefer closest point, don’t insert new vertices". However, It already projected new points on the road network....So what does "don’t insert new vertices" mean?

Also, there is another behavior named "Prefer aligning nodes....", when I searched about its meaning in https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=snap%20geometries%20ppoints#snap-geometries-to-layer, the QGIS documentation mentioned that it means: "Prefer to snap to nodes, even when a segment may be closer than a node." .... Isn't this supposed to be controlled via which layer is an input layer and which is a reference layer?